# While loop with dashes and numbers

Tags: php

I need to loop occurrences of a bunch of numbers in a string. I would like to parse the string and then echo out each number and a paragraph break.

Here is the string:

```
$string_of_numbers = "-173--37--141--79--274-";
```

how would i set up a while loop that could go through the numbers one at a time?

Comment: You could split trim the string and split it on `--`. Then you have an array of numbers (numeric strings).

Comment: You have the highest rep I've ever seen. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: What, you never heard about Jon Skeet? https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet ;)

Comment: @FelixKling may be he is taking about ratio 4.6k ans with 200k rep , 644k rep with 28k answer :P

Comment: Woah - you no longer have the highest rep I've ever seen... Haha thanks for the info.

Comment: FWIW, there are about 40 people with higher rep on this site... just saying. But hey, I accept the compliment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$string_of_numbers = "-173--37--141--79--274-";
$numbers = explode('--', trim($string_of_numbers, '-'));

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  echo $number;
}
```

With additional `array_walk` you can cast values from strings to integers:

```
array_walk($numbers, 'intval');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$str = "-173--37--141--79--274-";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

You can loop through the $matches which will have all the numbers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$string_of_numbers = "-173--37--141--79--274-";
$arr = explode("--", $string_of_numbers);

foreach($arr as $val)
{
  $val = str_replace("-", "", trim($val);
  echo $val; // each number you will get here
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
  $string_of_numbers = "-173--37--141--79--274-";
    $str = substr($string_of_numbers, 1, -1);
    $arr = explode("--", $str);

    foreach($arr as $val)
    {
      $val = trim($val);
      echo $val; // each number you will get here
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it better to remove first and last `-` before `explode` ?

Comment: Or `trim` as I described - you do not need to count string length :)

Comment: @hsz bro your answer is better than me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `preg_split()` function to explode the string by regular expression so you can get each string between "--". Php `explode()` function could also work.